# mvn Jetty run generates infinite error log

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty

> [WARNING] 
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/strategy/ProduceExecuteConsume$1
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ProduceExecuteConsume.produce(ProduceExecuteConsume.java:58)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$2.run(ManagedSelector.java:97)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This is the Warning i get when running Jetty:run in eclipse. Is there any way to fix that ? Jetty server wont start and it wont terminate. I am using 9.4.0.MO Jetty server and previously it worked just fine.

Comment: what was your previous version and also please share the exact command used to run jetty

Comment: @nullpointer I got it working by removing all the jetty dependency and using only the jetty plugin. I was and am using the same server.